# The c ++ stl library containers have dynamic memory allocations?

Tags: c++, vector, malloc, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I would like to know for example if to allocate memory dynamically I use new [] or malloc in std :: vector, or do not need, if I do not need, where should I use new [], malloc and smartpointers?

Comment: Sound like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you use c++, you would better use new [] method to allocate memory in heap because it is more safe than malloc method.

Comment: While using `malloc` should be avoided in C++ code, if you use the STL, then you almost never should need to use `new[]` directly.